# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Installation failed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, failed-installation

I've got a CLEVO x7200 (Intel i7 970 3.20GHz, 12Gb RAM, 2x512Gb HDD, 2xATI Radeon HD6970M 2Gb (Crossfire))

I have a very irritating problem. My laptop run with Windows 8.1 Pro. I would like to setup Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 , but it doesn't work. I tried with a lot of tips like **"Run as Administrator"**, **"Install the Microsoft Update KB200..."**, **"Setup by the Web Installer"**, **"Clear the Package Cache Folder in the C:\ProgramData folder"**, **"Shutdown the antivirus protection"**... but it doesn't work for me...

**EDIT (29/12/2013)** I tried to **reinstall the OS**. I downgrade to Windows 8.0, it doesn't still work. So I reupgrade to Windows 8.1.

**EDIT (01/01/2013)** I tried to **install with the Administrator account**, it doesn't still work.

**EDIT (07/01/2013)** I downloaded the Windows 8.1 Pro and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on DreamSpark (Microsoft Academy). The same version of my colleagues. I reinstall Windows 8.1 and tried to install Visual Studio on a naked configuration. It didn't work even though it works on my colleagues' PCs.

The installation starts well. But at a moment, it crashes and say that there's a fatal error during the setup and fail.

The window of the setup :
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/848000Sanstitre.png

I go to the logfile and I see that lines:
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/128176Capture.png

I don't understand why there's that problem. I have the 2012 version of Visual Studio and it works fine! May be my hardware configuration?

Comment: You could have a corrupt file for the install.  Have you tried re-downloading the installer?

Comment: Yes I retried lots of time but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to resolve my problem.
The missing component was : Microsoft .NET Platform 2.0

Visual Studio 2012 asked me if I would like to setup this functionality and I accepted. It had to be the issue. Well, now, Visual Studio 2013 is on my computer !

I don't know which people I have to thank =)

Bye!